# Cites with natbib, References and Bibliography with bibtopic

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, custom-bib

I am trying to mix `natbib` with `bibtopic`. The first I have been using with no problem for citing (`\citet{}` and `\citep{}`). However I need to have two sections with references: one with **cited** references ("References") and another with **all** references ("bibliography"). This is why I thought `bibtopic` would be of use.

However, I cannot make it work together. I have one file with all references (Tesis.bib) made with `bibtex`. I also have made a personalised bibliography style which I called `uady.bst`. Both files are in the same folder as my main .tex file.

```
\begin{btSect}[uady]{Tesis}
\chapter{Referencias}
\btPrintCited
\chapter{Bibliografía}
\btPrintAll
\end{btSect}
```

In my preamble I've declared like this the bib packages

```
\usepackage[authoryear,comma,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[defaultbib,verbose,breakcites]{bibtopic}
```

both after

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

The errors I am having are

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014) The top-level auxiliary file: Tesis.aux The style file: uady.bst I found no \bibdata command---while reading file  Tesis.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for ""...

This error appears the moment I declare the package so is not in the code but in the mix of `natbib` and `bibtopic`. In the `bibtopic` documentation it says that there is normally no problem with using both packages.

`\bibliographystyle{uady}` is declared just after `\begin{document}` and I am not using `\bibliography{Tesis}` since `bibtopic` says you shouldn't. Also, for every compilation I delete the previous *.aux and *.bbl files.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance